# How can I use 'create new collection' command?

Tags: collections

[image]

I create a collection with 'create new collection' command but the new collection did not appear in scene collection. And I found it in 'orphan data'. I tried to move the new collection(test) to scene collection but failed. I don't understand the way it works like that. How can I use the new 'test' collection?

Comment: Good question. No idea how that is supposed to be useful. Adding it in the outliner makes sense, but that shortcut in object mode doesn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is more or less a remnant of old functionality from 2.79 and before that doesn't make sense in Blender 2.8. [The developers are aware of the issue](https://developer.blender.org/T53662), multiple bug reports have been filed regarding the odd behavior.

If you want to create a new collection in the current scene use the <kbd>M</kbd> shortcut and select *New collection*. This will also move all selected objects to that new collection. If you just want to create an empty new collection with the shortcut, make sure that no object is selected.

Comment: ok. that is a bug!

Answer (score 0):

Hover over the outliner and press C to make a new collection without moving any objects into it. (in blender 2.835 anyway) Just pressing M gives an error 'no objects selected' as in the answer stated above.