# How can I quickly find the collection an object belongs to?

Tags: modeling, collections

I'm building a complex model that has many collections. Sometimes I add a new mesh to my model and it gets attached to the last collection I was working with. I need to move it to the appropriate collection. But it's not easy to find in the outliner.. So, is it possible to find which collection an object belongs without having to trawl through the outliner to find it ?

Comment: With the object selected in object mode you can use the shortcut key M to move to another collection easily. This way is quick and you do not have to be concerned which collection it currently belongs to. You can even create a new collection with this option.

Comment: @barkest you should publish that as an answer...+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response the op comment

In object mode with the object selected press <kbd>m</kbd>. Select the collection you want the object to belong to or add a new collection.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the 3d view-port sidebar panel - *View type*, there is a **"collection"** block to indicate which collection belong to the selected object.

[image]
(note that cube is in **both collections**, so both collections marks are filled)

You can also find it in **collection** block of **object properties panel**:

[image]

But careful about this Collection block, see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147763/how-can-i-use-create-new-collection-command)